# Multiple Global Settings for Play 2

Tags: java, playframework-2.0

Can I have two Global settings objects for Play2?

I know there is only setting available at application.conf.

```
global=common.GlobalOne
```

Two Global classes:

```
public class GlobalOne extends GlobalSettings {

  @Override
  public void onStart(Application app) {
      Logger.info("****** Set something ******");
  }

}

public class GlobalTwo extends GlobalSettings {

  @Override
  public void onStart(Application app) {
      Logger.info("****** some other ******");
  }

}
```

The reason I am asking is for play 2 modules. How to have a global setting object in a module so it can be enabled when a project uses it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That’s not possible. `GlobalSettings` apply to an application, not modules. Therefore, modules should not define a `GlobalSettings` object.

Answer (score 1):

I use such approach for merging multiple Global objects in root *Global.java*:

0) Folder structure:

```
/root
    /app
        Global.java
    /conf
        application.conf
    /subprojects
        /user
            /app
                /globals
                    UserGlobal.java
        /admin
            /app
                /globals
                    AdminGlobal.java
```

1) Put all subproject Global classes into *globals* package:

```
package globals;

public class UserGlobal extends GlobalSettings
{ ... }
```

2) Add configuration variable into all subproject conf files like a

```
application.global= globals.UserGlobal
```

3)  Add private field and private method in root *Global.java*:

```
private List<GlobalSettings> subprojectGlobals = new ArrayList<>();

private void LoadSubprojectGlobals(Application app)
    throws ClassNotFoundException, IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException
{
    Reflections reflections = new Reflections("globals");
    Set<Class<? extends GlobalSettings>> subprojectGlobalClasses = 
        reflections.getSubTypesOf(GlobalSettings.class);

    for(Class subprojectGlobalClass : subprojectGlobalClasses)
    {
        subprojectGlobals.add(
            (GlobalSettings)subprojectGlobalClass.newInstance()
        );
    }
}
```

4) Place such code into *onStart* event handler in root *Global.java*:

```
@Override
public void onStart(Application app)
{
    try
    {
        LoadSubprojectGlobals(app);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        new RuntimeException(e);
    }

    for(GlobalSettings subprojectGlobal: subprojectGlobals)
    {
        subprojectGlobal.onStart(app);
    }
}
```

Now if you add some new subproject you must follow some conventions about adding Global class but you have no need to modify anything for merging functionality.

If you want to handle more global settings you need to override appropriate method in root *Global.java*.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28365201/play-framework-merging-multiple-global-objects-in-multi-module-project) is my question about this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have a project split with a `main->frontend->common` and `main->backend->common` dependency. In each (common, frontend and backend) I have a GlobalSetting. I need this for running the tests.

Answer (score 0):

yes that is not possible because when you give request than play framework engine starts and it finds Global.java for the current Application or you can say Action method if it doesnot find than it skips that .So , bottomline is the class name which extends GlobalSettings should be Global.java