# Play Framework: merging multiple Global objects in multi-module project

Tags: playframework

I'm building a multi-module project using Play 2.3 and Java 8. Root application and each module have a Global object. But how we know Play uses only one Global object from root application.

Simplified folder structure:

```
/root
    /app
        Global.java
    /conf
        application.conf
    /subprojects
        /user
            /app
               UserGlobal.java
        /admin
            /app
               AdminGlobal.java
```

All Global classes placed in unnamed package.

I use such way for merging Global objects from subprojects:

1) Declared configuration variable in root *application.conf*

```
subprojects.with.globals="subprojectName1, subprojectName2, subprojectName3, ..."
```

2) Added private field and private method in root *Global.java*

```
private List<GlobalSettings> subprojectGlobals = new ArrayList<>();

private void LoadSubprojectGlobals(Application app)
    throws ClassNotFoundException, IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException
{
    String subprojectNames = 
        app.configuration().getString("subprojects.with.globals");
    if (!subprojectNames.isEmpty())
    {
        Class subprojectGlobalClass = null;
        for (String subprojectName : subprojectNames.split(","))
        {
            subprojectGlobalClass = Class.forName(
                WordUtils.capitalize(subprojectName.trim().toLowerCase()) +
                "Global"
            );
            subprojectGlobals.add(
                (GlobalSettings)subprojectGlobalClass.newInstance()
            );
        }
    }
}
```

3) Placed such code into *onStart* event handler in root *Global.java*

```
@Override
public void onStart(Application app)
{
    try
    {
        LoadSubprojectGlobals(app);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        new RuntimeException(e);
    }

    for(GlobalSettings subprojectGlobal: subprojectGlobals)
    {
        subprojectGlobal.onStart(app);
    }
}
```

Now if we add some new subproject we must edit *subprojects.with.globals* in root *application.conf*. And if we want to handle more global settings we need to override appropriate method in root *Global.java*.

It will be cool if we'll be able to determine all subproject names dynamically from java-code in root *onStart*. Is it possible? May be from root *build.sbt* or from Application object?

**UPDATE**

I changed my project applying @Mon Calamari's approach.

1) Removed configuration variable *subprojects.with.globals* from root *application.conf*.

2) Put all subproject Global classes into *globals* package:

```
/subprojects
    /user
        /app
            /globals
                UserGlobal.java
    /admin
        /app
            /globals
                AdminGlobal.java
```

3) Added configuration variable into all subproject conf files like a

```
application.global= globals.UserGlobal
```

4) Changed *LoadSubprojectGlobals()* implementation:

```
private void LoadSubprojectGlobals(Application app)
    throws ClassNotFoundException, IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException
{
    Reflections reflections = new Reflections("globals");
    Set<Class<? extends GlobalSettings>> subprojectGlobalClasses = 
        reflections.getSubTypesOf(GlobalSettings.class);

    for(Class subprojectGlobalClass : subprojectGlobalClasses)
    {
        subprojectGlobals.add(
            (GlobalSettings)subprojectGlobalClass.newInstance()
        );
    }
}
```

Now if we add some new subproject we must follow some conventions about adding Global class but we have no need to keep track sub projects list.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure how your modules/packages are arranged, but what if you use `org.reflections` to get all extensions of `play.GlobalSettings` class:

```
Reflections reflections = new Reflections("your.package");    
Set<Class<? extends GlobalSettings>> classes = reflections.getSubTypesOf(GlobalSettings.class)
```

Comment: thank you very much. I tried your approach. It works and I think it fits for me. I'm going to update my post for more clarifying tomorrow.